# Unable to check diffs with TortoiseGit: "fatal: empty string is not a valid pathspec"

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Currently, I did a re-installation of my windows 10. I also installed Git and TortoiseGit.

Right now when I try to check diffs I have theses two errors in a window:

> fatal: empty string is not a valid pathspec, please use . instead if
>   you meant to match all paths

I click ok, then the other window error is:

> Failed to get UnRev file list fatal: empty string is not a valid
>   pathspec, please use . instead if you meant to match all paths

I click ok and it does not show me any errors in the "working tree" diffs.

Git.exe is in :

> C:\Program Files\Git\bin

And the path is set correctly in the General menu (settings) of Tortoisegit.

Anyone know how to fix this issue ? Thanks.

Comment: Download Beyond Compare and connect it Tortoise GIT as an external diff tool (right click anywhere, choose TortoiseGIT --> Settings --> Diff Viewer, mark 'External' and enter 'C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4\BCompare.exe' in the edit box).

Comment: Same issue. I followed theses instructions https://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs#tortoisegit and I replaced the path by : C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4 (not x86)

Comment: NOTE: Unlike TortoiseGit, Beyond Compare (the utility recommended by the comments above) is not free software (it's $60); **I'd recommend just updating TortoiseGit, which will fix the problem this question is talking about.** But if you really want a third party comparison utility, I'd recommend [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/), which is free.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

TortoiseGit 2.5 is not yet fully compatible to Git >= 2.16. See https://TortoiseGit.org and the corresponding bug report: https://TortoiseGit.org/issue/3138

**Update:** Use the latest stable version of TortoiseGit: https://tortoisegit.org/download/

Comment: Thanks. I did some research for half hour yesterday and I did not find this topic. Issue fixed by downgrading to git 2.15.2

Comment: it is terrible that this is not made very clear before upgrading tools. now I will be more cautious with TortoiseGit and Git

Comment: Ran into the same issue here.  I upgraded to TortoiseGit 2.6.0.0 (kept Git 2.16.2) and now the "Check for modifications" dialog is working again.  Thanks!