# TortoiseGit - Add - fatal - empty string is not valid pathspec

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Tried right-click "Add" on the TortoiseGit menu from the root of my project, and I see this error: "Fatal: empty string is not valid pathsepc. please use . instead if you mean to match all paths. 
[image]

Part 2 - can I do a recursive add from all subdirectories?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to check diffs with TortoiseGit: "fatal: empty string is not a valid pathspec"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48452665/unable-to-check-diffs-with-tortoisegit-fatal-empty-string-is-not-a-valid-path)

Comment: Maybe different cause, but same symptom/reason.  I am on Tortoise Git 2.5.0 and git version is 2.16.1 (for windows)

Comment: That's exact the very same procedure called in TortoiseGit which fails here.

Comment: I upgrade to 2.6 and seems like the problem went away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48457419/3906760:

---

TortoiseGit 2.5 is not yet fully compatible to Git >= 2.16. See https://TortoiseGit.org and the corresponding bug report: https://TortoiseGit.org/issue/3138

Use the latest stable version of TortoiseGit: https://tortoisegit.org/download/

Answer (score 1):

Installing Tortise Get 2.6 solved the problem.